# Find numbers ending in 00 or 50 but only in a certain line

Tags: notepad++, regex

Basically I have this

```
<Placemark>
        <name>9795</name>
        <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0198045,52.231084,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>9800</name>
        <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0198629,52.23109400000001,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name>9805</name>
        <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0199357,52.231112,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

And I want to turn it into this

```
<Placemark>
        <name>9800</name>
        <description><![CDATA[converted by:</br><a href="http://gridreferencefinder.com/">GridReferenceFinder.com</a></br>]]></description>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-1.0198629,52.23109400000001,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
```

but I have thousands of lines. I want to search the groups and delete the ones that dont have 00 or 50 at the end of the number in the line `<name>number</name>`

Comment: why is `9805`missing in your result?

Comment: This goes upto 30000 and goes up in 5's. I just need the code with the number 00 or 50 at the end in the line name

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by doing a XSL Transformation. You can do this by adding the [XML Tools](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-plugins/files/XML%20Tools/) plugin to your Notepad++.

Create a new xsl file with the following transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
        <xsl:sort select="Placemark/name"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="Placemark['00' != substring(name, string-length(name) - string-length('00') +1) and '50' != substring(name, string-length(name) - string-length('50') +1)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The transformation will copy all `Placemark` nodes having a `name` that ends with `00` or `50` to the result.

Now you can open you XML file. Go to Plugins --> XML Tools --> XSL Transformation. Select the created xls file and do the transformation.